# Link multiple tables to one geometry layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, dbf

I have a QGIS-project with **one geometry layer** (.shp), with some attributes, and **multiple tables without geometry** (.dbf). The different tables and the geometry layer share a column with unique ID-numbers, making it possible to join eachother.

However, I don't want to add extra columns from my .dbf-tables to the attributetable of the shapefile (by using join), I want to link all the layers to eachother. More specifically, if I select a geometry in the shapefile-layer, and it's record gets highlighted in the according attribute table, also the other related records are highlighted in all the linked .dbf-files. Is that possible? What is the most easy way to fix this (without hardcore coding)?

The aim: to link and easily find all the according/related records of one geometry in different layers if I click it, to make the necessairy changes in all the tables at once.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seem you need to create relation rather than join : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#creating-one-or-many-to-many-relations